# How do I make set a google script trigger to run again if there is an error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet to keep stack of live stock prices and portfolio valuations. 
Also, I have some script which runs once a day to provide a permanent record of the valuation.
However, sometimes the stock prices do not load immediately, so the permanent record contains errors.
What is the best way of fixing this ?     For example, can I set a trigger to repeat after 30 minutes if there are errors in certain cells ?
I did try a loop to repeat the process within the script if there was an error, but as the maximum time google script can run for is about 5 minutes, it is not effective.

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvi1k.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to set up a control sheet with two variables:

- has the script run today? True/False
- does the sheet have errors? True/False (by using the isError() formula on the portfolio sheet)

Trigger One: trigger a script first thing in the morning to set the "Has the script run today" value to 'False'.

Trigger Two: trigger a second script (say) every hour to check if

- the main script run today? False >> Run main script || True >> check for errors
- does the sheet have errors? True >> Run main script || False >> end

You could run Trigger Two more or less frequently depending on how many iterations it takes to get rid of all the errors.

But do remember that there is a quota for the total trigger run time as well: [90 min per day for a consumer account](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Comment: Thank you.  I have done something similar that runs the main script once.   Then a second script will run if there is an error from the first, several times if necessary.